# Rotate OpenGL quad around its center

Tags: opengl, graphics

Sorry, I searched it but couldn't figure how to apply it to my code reading the other answers to similar questions. I what to rotate a quad, my code is the following:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, player_texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
    glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue());
    glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex2f(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue(), hero.yValue());
    glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex2f(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue(), hero.yValue()+hero.hValue());
    glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex2f(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue()+hero.hValue());  
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I'm not sure about how to use the glTranslatef function, I tell it what is the center of my object?

In that case it would be:
*hero.xValue()+hero.lValue()/2* **(x)** and *hero.yValue()+hero.hValue()/2*  **(y)**

I know I have to use both glTranslatef and glRotate, by the way. When I try, setting glTranslatef with the values I mentioned above, I get a texture floating far from where the hero actually is.

Any help on this matter will be appreciated, thank you.

Obs: hValue = height, lValue = lenght

Edit: New information to show the changes I made after @user55564's comment:

I call init() once, on there I set basic openGL and SDL stuff, among them:

```
glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

then I call my draw function, it has in it:

```
while (running) {
    glLoadIdentity();

.
. stuff non-related to drawing
.

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);

    // draws the player     
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, player_texture);
    glTranslatef(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue(), 0);
    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue()/2), -(hero.yValue()+hero.hValue()/2), 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
        glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue());
        glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex2f(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue(), hero.yValue());
        glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex2f(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue(), hero.yValue()+hero.hValue());
        glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex2f(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue()+hero.hValue());  
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();

// then I use pushmatrix again to draw the enemies and the health bars of both enemies and player (these don't need rotation);
glPushMatrix();
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
.
.
.
```

Comment: You're using ultra-old and deprecated opengl-functions. If you learned this in a tutorial, look for a newer better tutorial. Btw: You rotate with glRotate. glTranslate is to move it.

Comment: I know that, I just found they to be super simple to use and decided to use them on this first simple project which is almost finished by now. All I have to do is call glRotate with the desired angle of rotation?

Comment: Yes, your angle as first parameter and for a 2D game the last three parameters should be 0, 0 and 1.

Comment: No texture is shown for the hero when I call glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1); before glBegin() and glRotatef(-90, 0, 0, 1); after glEnd()

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your matrix. Are you loading the identitymatrix everytime before rendering?

Comment: I'm using glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);, GL_PROJECTION matrix mode and calling glLoadIdentity(); only once. btw, I don't think it stopped being rendered, has only been moved off screen.

Comment: I did some research and I am pretty sure I will have to translate it to be able to rotate and have the texture on the same place (rotate around its center)

Comment: Yeah... Don't do that. Set up your projection-matrix once and then use modelview for rendering. Call loadIdentity once every frame (at the beginning) and please use pushmatrix and popmatrix instead of rotating back, this can go horribly wrong in some cases.

Comment: Ok, I'm using push and pop matrix by the way, but putting all drawing inside of it. I'm algo using glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
Same thing happenig with modelview though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do to draw a quad with x,y as its top left coords, r as rotation, and cx and cy as the center of rotation (relative to its x,y coord) :

```
- translate(x,y)
- rotate(r)
- translate(cx, cy);
- draw.
- (reverse/pop the matrix if required. etc)
```

For your case, try this:

```
...
glTranslatef(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue(), 0);
glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(+hero.lValue()/2, +hero.hValue()/2);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
    glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(-hero.lValue()/2, -hero.hValue()/2);
    // do the same for other 3 corners.

glEnd();
```

After the transformations, your (0,0) coord is at where the object's center is. Suppose if object is at (50,50). In your function after the transformation the (0,0) is at (50,50) So if you draw at (50,50) again then in reality you are drawing your object at (100,100).

See http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/ for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you! It's almost there, but it doesn't actually do a rotation around its center, it is a bit off after the rotation.
Off to the left and up, it seems, no more than half of one side of the hero (square, 50x50);

Comment: Try it with `translate(-cx, -cy)` taken out; if that doesnt work try it with `translate(+cx, +cy);`

Comment: Doesnt work either, the hero gets rendereng far away from his spot texture), off screen actually, but I can manage to move him in.

Comment: Did you reset the transformations properly before drawing? Like with `glIdentity` before `translate(x,y)`. If that doesnt work you have to post your drawing function.

Comment: Here is a image of what is happening:
http://prntscr.com/5fcecz
The red bar is the player's health, since it is full it represents the same lenght as the player and should be right above it.

I have glLoadIdentity(); on the begining of each frame.
I am using glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); glPushMatrix(); and glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1); before drawing.

Comment: Obs: the image shows the player with rotation = 0 deg
I edited my first post with more information.

Comment: Your `glTranslatef(-(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue()/2), -(hero.yValue()+hero.hValue()/2), 0);` is wrong. It should be `hero.lValue()/2` only (I assume it meant width). It should be relative to its x,y coord not an absolute value. Also your `glVertex2f(hero.xValue(), hero.yValue());` is wrong. This is applying translation twice. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: lValue is the lenght of the spaceship, hValue the height, did you meant to use hValue instead of yValue on glVertex, on your answer?

Comment: Yes fixed. See edit. Length (if you mean the difference from x1 to x0) is usually called width.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand how I am supposed to set the 4 corners on this format, how is the top left corner (+width/2, -height/2)?

Comment: (-width/2, -height/2) Sorry. If you want some more explanation on why see http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/

Comment: After your edit I understood, but drawing it this way I got the same exact result as before when not using the translate(-cx, -cy). When using it the texture rotates around a center and is displayed on one different quadrant for each 90deg variation in angle.

Comment: The draw() function, if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/Pkd0m0zw

Comment: Translate to x+width/2, y + height/2 directly. `glTranslatef(hero.xValue()+hero.lValue()/2, hero.yValue()+hero.hValue()/2, 0);`

Comment: Yesss! Thank you, that did it. I'm reading the article you posted too. Thank you very much!